# python 3 - jack-client - using write_midi_event - jack keeps sending the midi event forever

Tags: python-3.x

I try to use python **jack-client** module to send a program change midi when I click on a button

here is a simplified version of the code :

```
def process_callback(frames: int):
    global midiUi
    if(midiUi is not None):
        midiUi.process_callback(frames)    

class MidiUi:
    
    def __init__(self):

        self.client = jack.Client('MidiUi')
        self.client.set_process_callback(process_callback)
        self.client.activate()

    def sendProgramChange(self):
        self.midiQueue.append([0xC0,0])
        
    def process_callback(self,frames: int):

        while(len(self.midiQueue)>0):
            data = self.midiQueue.pop()
            self.outMidiPort.clear_buffer()
            buffer = self.outMidiPort.reserve_midi_event(0,len(data))
            buffer[:] = bytearray(data)
            self.outMidiPort.write_midi_event(0,buffer) # this only happens once yet midi input receives tons of program changes events 
            #raise jack.CallbackExit

midiUi = MidiUi()

while True:
    ....
    #some button calls midiUi.sendProgramChange()
```

**write_midi_event** is called only once when pressing the button,

but apparently the destination midi port receives a continuous flow of midi C0 program changes (unless I call jack.CallbackExit, but then the call back never triggers again)

(I monitor my python script output using jack_midi_dump and midisnoop)

anyone know how to solve this ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I now user python-rtmidi for this matter

```
midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut(rtapi=rtmidi.API_UNIX_JACK)
rtMidiOutputPorts=midiout.get_ports()
```

then write data to the port

Answer (score 0):

This post may be kind of old and it seems like you've got it figured out, but I did find a solution:

The midi client is sending whatever is in the buffer, which means that things like **write_midi_event** need to be cleared to stop sending it. Therefore, what helped me was near the beginning of my process, I had;

**outport.clear_buffer()**

Hope that helps ;)